# flutter url_launcher email formatting

Tags: flutter

I have an app that sends email via url_launcher.

```
final Uri _emailLaunchUri = Uri(
  scheme: 'mailto',
  path: '',
  queryParameters: {
    'subject': 'History Report',
    'body': 'This is line 1\nThis is line2\nThis is line3',
  },
);

var newurl = _emailLaunchUri.toString();

if (await canLaunch(newurl)) {
  await launch(newurl);
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch $newurl';
}
```

When using default IOS mail app, I get line breaks as expected.  If I use the gmail app on IOS, the there is no line break.

Any ideas on how to get line breaks with the gmail app?

Thanks.

Comment: try `\r\n` .....

Comment: Well that works!  Now all the mail apps show it the same way.  Odd that \n worked for IOS default mail app, but not gmail or Outlook app.  Thanks!